# Changing mouse behaviour in EOG

Tags: 12.04, mouse-scroll, eog

When I open a photo in eog I can easily zoom with the mouse mouse wheel. This is kind of nice but since I have a touchpad with two-fingered scrolling and horizontal scrolling I'd rather scroll in the image and zoom by using Ctrl+Mouse Wheel?

I basically want the same behaviour as in evince:
Horizontal Scroll and Normal Scroll navigate within the image and Ctrl + Mouse Wheel zooms in and out.

Is this possible somehow?

[EDIT]
I just figured out that what I want is already implemented: I can pan the image by using Ctrl + Mouse Wheel. This is fine as it is the behaviour I want only with the Ctrl inverted.
But I cannot pan to the left. Up, down and right work fine. What's the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wauzl, try to set value of the property «scroll-wheel-zoom» to false.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.eog.view scroll-wheel-zoom false
```

Also, you can list other EOG properties:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i eog
```

Comment: Setting `org.gnome.eog.view scroll-wheel-zoom` to `true` not only anwered my question but also enables me to pan to the left. Is this a bug in eog or due to my settings?

Comment: I use Eye of Mate, with the Mate Desktop. I'm kind of guessing the same should more or less apply, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the backwards keybindings under eom - Eye of Mate, use the following:

```
gsettings set org.mate.eom.view scroll-wheel-zoom false
```

Then restart it.  ;-)